# Priority of a married woman: husband or terminally-ill parents?

Tags: husband-wife, parents

I got married eight months back and moved to the USA with my husband. Both my parents are aged and suffer from terminally ill diseases.

My husband is very understanding and he sent me immediately to my home (India) to look after my parents. Now I'm with my parents for the past six months, while my husband is still in the USA.

My in-laws are worried that I'm not with my husband and they are asking me to go back to the USA. My in-laws are also good people but they are asking me how long I can stay with my parents as it is also the duty of a woman to stay with her husband.

I don't know what to do now? Whom should I stay with, and who gets the priority?

Comment: IMO we can't answer this question for you as: Basically the husband has priority but when it comes to details scholars may have differences on to what extent you may act against this general "rule". It is your husband who can solve the issue, either by ordering you to come and stay with him, or tell his parents that he agrees with you staying with your parents due to the circumstance. But You should always keep asking him whether he is fine with the situation and try to find a way to be close to him, so that he might not feel neglected. Both of you should sincerly speak things out.

Comment: My comment above is one of many opinions you may get therefore I suppose that this question -as is- is rather attracting opinion based answers (off-topic). I strongly recommend you to edit to make it answerable (see [ask]).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this requires a fatwa by a knowledgeable scholar. After examining the different jurisprudential views, a general blanket answer is not possible.